# Update UI when returning from a deep link in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I am deep linking my app into Settings, and I love the new iOS 9 feature to bring the user right back to my app. However, I need to update my UI when the user returns.

I can update the UI before the transition, but the user notices the update. I have set breakpoints at `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear` and `viewWillDisappear`, and no luck.

What gets called when using the new "Return to ..." feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen the notification UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. And then, call some function to update your UI.

I've never used this, but this blogpost talks about that. http://www.codingexplorer.com/updating-an-app-when-returning-from-background-in-ios/